# Connect to postgres data base through corporate proxy

Tags: postgresql, proxy, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect to postgresql database that locate in my home using pgAdmin or Qgis, but in company, where I work, admin create proxy-server http(s)//company.proxy.com:8080
How can I connect to database?

Also, there is redmine on that server and when I connect to it using google chrome with settings-network-change proxy setting - it work fine...